# How to Install Lenovo Slim Usb Keyboard (SK-8821) F1-F12 Keys on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have Windows 10 Pro x64 and installed on **[Lenovo V520 MT-M 10NK](https://www3.lenovo.com/za/en/desktops/lenovo/lenovo-v-series-tower/Lenovo-V520-15IKL-Tower/p/11LV1VDV520)**
And i also have the **Lenovo Slim Usb Keyboard** (Model: **SK-8821**) that comes with it.

[image: Compact Keyboard with no dedicated F-keys]

When I press the buttons **F1,F2,F3** and so, I got nothing.
If I press the **Fn+F1** buttons the F Keys are working.

How do I change the F Keys to work **immediately** without pressing the **Fn** Key together?

Also, where can I find the correct Software/Driver for this?

I try searching [**the web**](http://blog.lenovo.com/en/blog/switching-function-keys-to-standard-f1-f12-on-lenovo-slim-usb-keyboard) and the [**Lenovo support center**](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/at/en/search?query=%5BDriver%5D%20Lenovo%20slim%20USB%20Keyboard%20Driver%20for%20Windows%2010&searchLocation=searchPage_S) but not got any solution for **Windows 10**.  It works only on windows 7/8/8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't have F1, F2, F3 keys. Those are Mute, Quieter, Louder keys.

See [USB HID Keyboard Scan codes](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2) -

```
#define KEY_MEDIA_VOLUMEUP 0xed  
#define KEY_MEDIA_VOLUMEDOWN 0xee  
#define KEY_MEDIA_MUTE 0xef
```

To change the meaning of those keys, you must install a suitable driver.

Windows 8.1 drivers sometimes work on Windows 10.

You may be able to do some remapping using some other generic driver or keyboard/scancode [remapping tool](https://windowsreport.com/keyboard-mapping-software-windows-10/).

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/a/677452/21244) a solution that works cross-platform, and does not require installing any unwanted software:

Simply fold a piece of paper 4 times, then cut to desired size so you don't get papercuts, and jam it in with the Fn button pressed.

I tested it myself; works beautifully.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/794483)

Comment: @Ramhound I **did** incude the essential part of the answer (folding the paper, and jamming it with the button).

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked to download the Windows 8 driver, extract it and then run the "Lenovo Slim USB Keyboard" tool from where the driver was extracted. No remapping tool required.

1. Download the drivers from the [Lenovo drivers page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS032471) (or search for "Lenovo slim USB Keyboard driver")
2. Extract the driver (usually to "C:\SWTOOLS\DRIVERS")
3. run "Lenovo Slim USB Keyboard.exe" in C:\SWTOOLS\DRIVERS\KEYBOARD\c6kyb05us17\x64
4. There you can tick a checkbox for using the FN keys primarily

Hope that works!